# Filter record from one data frame based on column values in second data frame in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have two DataFrame **df1** and **df2**.

df1 is the original dataset and **df2** is the dataset made from df1 after some manipulation.

In **df1** I have column **'log'** and in **df2** I have column **'log1'** and **'log2'** two columns.

where the values in columns **'log1'** and **'log2'** contains in column **'log'** in **df1**.

**df2 sample below**

```
date  id     log1    log2
1   uu1q    (2,4)   (3,5)
1   uu1q    (2,4)   (7,6)
1   uu1q    (3,5)   (7,6)
5   u25a    (4,7)   (3,9)
5   uu25a   (1,9)   (3,9)
6   ua3b7   (1,1)   (2,2)
6   ua3b7   (1,1)   (3,3)
6   ua3b7   (2,2)   (3,3)
```

**df1 column sample with data below**

```
date id     log    name   col1  col2
1   uu1q    (2,4)   xyz   1123  qqq
1   uu1q    (3,5)   aas   2132  wew
1   uu1q    (7,6)   wqas  2567  uuo
5   u25a    (4,7)   enj   666   ttt
5   fff     (0,0)   ddd   0     lll
```

Now I want to take fetch/filter all the records from **df1** based on column values for each row in **df2** i.e. based on `'date'`, `'id'`, `'log1'` or `'log2'` and compare it with columns in **df1** i.e.
`'date'`, `'id'`, `'log'`.

**NOTE:** values columns **'log1'** and **'log2'** contained in single column **'log'**

Comment: Can you provide a sample of df1? and desired output?

Comment: @keramat I have provided the df1 sample. I just want to filter all the data in df1 based on row values in df2 i.e. i want to compare df1.date = df2.date , df1.id = df2.id , (df1.log = df2.log1 or df1.log = df2.log2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you're looking for a chained `isin`:

```
out = df1[df1['date'].isin(df2['date']) & df1['id'].isin(df2['id']) & (df1['log'].isin(df2['log1']) | df1['log'].isin(df2['log2']))]
```

Output:

```
   date    id    log  name  col1 col2
0     1  uu1q  (2,4)   xyz  1123  qqq
1     1  uu1q  (3,5)   aas  2132  wew
2     1  uu1q  (7,6)  wqas  2567  uuo
3     5  u25a  (4,7)   enj   666  ttt
```

Comment: @jezrael could you elaborate? `&` should compare them together, no?

Comment: hmmm, thinking. Why never seen this merge alternative. Seems working. And why is not used - I guess because bad performance.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) for column `log` from `log1, log2...` columns and for filtering inner join in [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
df = (df2.melt(['date','id'], value_name='log')
         .drop('variable', axis=1)
         .drop_duplicates()
         .merge(df1))
print (df)
   date    id    log  name  col1 col2
0     1  uu1q  (2,4)   xyz  1123  qqq
1     1  uu1q  (3,5)   aas  2132  wew
2     5  u25a  (4,7)   enj   666  ttt
3     1  uu1q  (7,6)  wqas  2567  uuo
```

Comment: I want to filter all the records from df1 where this below condition meets for each row in df2
```[df1.date == df2.date and df1.id == df2.id and (df1.log == df2.log1 or df1.log == df2.log2)]```